# I Have A Link Set to Not Appear But It's Still Showing Up

Tags: html, css

You may find it hard to believe but I've been trying to figure out why this won't work for hours and if anyone could show me what I'm doing wrong, I'd be most appreciative.

On a page of my site I have a list of navigational links but I don't want the "Home" link to appear while on the home page so I assigned it a class and set this class to not show the link but it's not working.

Here's what I have for the link

```
<li><a href='http://classifieds.your-adrenaline-fix.com/' class='homelink'>Classifieds Home</a></li>
```

and just before the closing head tag of the index.php page I have;

```
<style type="text/css">.homelink { display:none; }</style>
```

yet, The link is appearing. If anyone could kindly show me how to make this work properly I'd be most appreciative and I thank you in advance.

Comment: Cannot reproduce — http://jsbin.com/acemut/1/edit — Your question does not contain whatever it is that is causing your problem. Try producing a reduced test case that reproduces the problem.

Comment: do you have any other CSS that might be re-enabling it?

Comment: Do you use JS? Or other CSS?

Comment: PS Load your page in Firefox (or other decent browser), open Firebug (or similar dev tools) pick the link, and view the styles for it.  They will indicate which part of the CSS or inline styles are responsible for it showing up, color, font, background, etc.

Comment: Could you post the rest (or the most relevant bits) of your CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Try seeing if its a specificity conflict by instead using the `!important` keyword

```
.homelink {
display: none !important;
}
```

Or add it as an inline style:

`<li><a href='http://classifieds.your-adrenaline-fix.com/' style="display: none;">Classifieds Home</a></li>`

Comment: I thank you for showing me the !important KW. Adding this did correct this but please tell me... Is having that KW in place a "Patch"??  If you (or anyone) could review the page's source code (see link in my first post) and let me know if everything looks proper I'd be most appreciative

Comment: Well its not the best practice to use them - they are valid CSS but ideally you want to figure out where the specificity conflict occurs (I suggest using firebug for such a thing) and change the selector so that its more specific. This is a good article for more info on the topic: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
 display: none !important;
```

i think there is another class or "a" tag in css